# Share tweet not working

Tags: javascript

I built a random quote machine for a challenge and one of the requirements is to include a tweet button which I did.
The only issue is that the tweet button works on my machine locally and I was able to tweet a quote **BUT ONLY in Google Chrome**, if I use Firefox Developer Edition or Codepen, the tweet button does not work even if the code is exactly the same.

https://codepen.io/HacNass/full/QQMRNR/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#newQuote").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/popular.json", function(json) {

        // getting a random number to pick a json object randomly
        var jsonLength = json.length;
        var randomQuoteNumber;
        function getRandomInt(randomInt) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(randomInt));
        };

        randomQuoteNumber = getRandomInt(jsonLength);
        console.log(randomQuoteNumber);

        // Store the random quote machine composnents in respective variables   
        var randomQuote = json[randomQuoteNumber].quote;
        var randomAuthor = json[randomQuoteNumber].author;

        // update the html elements with a random quote and author from the json API
        $("#quoteHolder").html(randomQuote);
        $("#author").html(randomAuthor);

        $("#tweetButton").on("click", function() {
            $("a").attr("href", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=randomQuoteMachine&text="
                                                    + encodeURIComponent(randomQuote + " - " + randomAuthor));
        });


    });
});
```

});

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why would you want to change the href attribute of **each** `a` on click of the tweet button? Is this a hack to navigate to that twitter link? Why not just set the `location.href` to switch to another url?

Comment: because I have only one `a` which is redirecting to the tweet web intent page to share the tweet and I am changing the attributes of that only `a` to fill the tweet!